# What's the difference between UIView.animate() and UIButton.animate()?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change the opacity of my button to half when pressed, and animate that change. So I was searching for how to do that and found this piece of code:

```
    @IBAction func keyPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3)
        {
            sender.alpha = 0.5
        }
```

I got curious as to why we called the `animate` function on a `UIView` not on a `UIButton`, as what we want to animate is, specifically, a `UIButton`. So I tried `UIButton.animate()` and to my eyes it gives the same result with the animation.

So what's the difference? Is there a reason the person posting this code preferred using `UIView.animate()` over `UIButton.animate()`?

Comment: Actually `Self.animate` is the cleanest way if self is a view. But it makes no difference because you have not overridden this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `animate` function is a class level function of `UIView` so it is common to use it as `UIView.animate...`.

Since `UIButton` ultimately extends `UIView`, using `UIButton.animate...` also works. You could even use `UIScrollView.animate...`, for example, in your `UIButton` code. Obviously that would be confusing but it would work.

In any code within a `UIView` subclass, using `Self.animate...` also works.

But the basic answer to your question is that people use `UIView.animate...` because `animate` is defined in the `UIView` class.

Comment: UIButton inherits from UIControl which inherits from UIView

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, via UIControl, which is why I stated that UIButton ultimately extends UIView. :)

Comment: I get it now. So it doesn't matter which `animate` function I use, it won't affect the animation. That means the `animate` function in `UIButton` isn't different or modified from the function in `UIView`, because it basically inherits it, is that right?

Comment: Unless the documentation for a given UIView subclass specifically shows that it overrides the `animate` function (and I don't know of any that do), then there is only the one `animate` method provided by UIView and referencing it by any other UIView subclass will give the same result.